# Страница пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать проверку, принадлежит страница пользователю или нет? В сессии записаны пароль, лог id и если это его страница из db вывести его логин. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Выведете данные по его Id, а там и логин получите.

> Как сделать проверку принадлежит страница пользователю или нет

у каждой страницы должно быть поле user_id и сравнивайте его с Id пользователем.

Comment: У меня в БД вместо user id просто id.

Answer (score 2):

так добавьте поле user_id к таблице со страницами пользователей.. при создании новой страницы в user_id записывайте ID пользователя